# Use List Names as Row Names When Converting From pmap to pmap_dfr purrr

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

I have a pmap function that extracts stock data. When I use pmap() I get a list with the list names as the tickers. When I use pmap_dfr() I get a dataframe but the row names are indexed 1:N. I would like the rownames to be the tickers.

```
pmap(df, ~reqMktData(tws, twsOption(local = "", symbol = ..1, expiry = ..2, strike = ..3, right = "P"), eventWrapper = eWrapper.data(1), 
                     CALLBACK = snapShot))

[[1]]
    BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize Last LastSize Volume
AEM       0       -1       -1       0 0.73       14    275

[[2]]
    BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize Last LastSize Volume
AEM       0       -1       -1       0 1.39        1     19

[[3]]
    BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize Last LastSize Volume
BHC       0       -1       -1       0  0.7       20     26

[[4]]
    BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize Last LastSize Volume
BHC       0       -1       -1       0 1.15        1      1


pmap_dfr(df, ~reqMktData(tws, twsOption(local = "", symbol = ..1, expiry = ..2, strike = ..3, right = "P"), eventWrapper = eWrapper.data(1), 
                     CALLBACK = snapShot))

 BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize Last LastSize Volume
1       0       -1       -1       0 0.73       14    261
2       0       -1       -1       0 1.39        1     18
3       0       -1       -1       0 0.70       20     46
4       0       -1       -1       0 1.15        1      1
```

The desired output would be:

```
      BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize Last LastSize Volume
AEM       0       -1       -1       0 0.73       14    261
AEM       0       -1       -1       0 1.39        1     18
BHC       0       -1       -1       0 0.70       20     46
BHC       0       -1       -1       0 1.15        1      1
```

An even better output would be:

```
 Ticker   BidSize BidPrice AskPrice AskSize Last LastSize Volume
1    AEM      0       -1       -1       0 0.73       14    261
2    AEM      0       -1       -1       0 1.39        1     18
3    BHC      0       -1       -1       0 0.70       20     46
4    BHC      0       -1       -1       0 1.15        1      1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new column with `rownames` of the list.

```
purrr::map_dfr(lst_df, ~{.x$ticker <- rownames(.x);.x})
```

---

Contrarily, if you use

```
df1 <- do.call(rbind, lst_df)
```

the rownames are maintained which can be converted to column names if needed

```
df1$ticker <- rownames(df1)
```

where

```
lst_df <- pmap(df, ~reqMktData(tws, twsOption(local = "", symbol = ..1, 
          expiry = ..2, strike = ..3, right = "P"), 
          eventWrapper = eWrapper.data(1), CALLBACK = snapShot))
```

Comment: Ronak if you do not mind, I have a follow up. Let's say I have 2 lists that I want to do this on. Will I have to call purrr::map_dfr(lst_df1, ~{.x$ticker <- rownames(.x);.x}) and again on list 2? purrr::map_dfr(lst_df2, ~{.x$ticker <- rownames(.x);.x}) . Thanks

Comment: @JordanWrong You can do that or put the 2 lists in a list and use another `map`, `map(list(lst_df1, lst_df2), ~map_dfr(.x, ~{.x$ticker <- rownames(.x);.x}))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `tibble::rownames_to_column()` in the original call, then you can use `pmap_dfr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap_dfr(df, ~reqMktData(
  tws, 
  twsOption(local = "", symbol = ..1, expiry = ..2, strike = ..3, right = "P"), 
  eventWrapper = eWrapper.data(1), 
  CALLBACK = snapShot) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Ticker"))
```